# livewire and vite not playing together well; livewire produces a blank screen when data coming from function updated($property)

Tags: laravel, tailwind-css, vite, laravel-livewire, alpine.js

I have just created a new laravel project, using sail / docker.  Installed tailwind, laravel-livewire, alpine.  my package.json looks like this:

```
{
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "vite",
        "build": "vite build"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "autoprefixer": "^10.4.13",
        "axios": "^1.1.2",
        "laravel-vite-plugin": "^0.6.0",
        "lodash": "^4.17.19",
        "postcss": "^8.4.18",
        "tailwindcss": "^3.2.2",
        "vite": "^3.0.0"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "@alpinejs/focus": "^3.10.5",
        "@defstudio/vite-livewire-plugin": "^0.2.6",
        "@tailwindcss/forms": "^0.5.3",
        "alpinejs": "^3.10.5"
    }
}
```

I have a livewire component, a form, that you choose your Property that you live in, then choose the unit on that property.  People are making maintenance requests for their apartment to their apartment manager.

So when the user / tenant identifies their property, function updated($property) does the validation only for the field that changed, then if passes, runs a query to find the list of apartments available for that property.  I dd() at the end of the function and I know it is returning the proper list of apartments and their id's for the property chosen in the form.

However, as soon as livewire tries to send the data back to the form, I get a totally blank screen.  In fact, I don't think the data is making it out of the back end because in the console, I do not see the apartment unit request being returned, but again, on the back end, if I dd($units), they are all their.

I think it is a Vite / livewire issue going on.  I cannot identify it.

Here is the code in the livewire component.  I include the dd(), and it does return the appropriate values to the screen, so the app is getting to the end of the updated() function:

```
 public function updated($propertyname)
    {
        $this->validateOnly($propertyname, $this->rules(), $this->customMessages());
        switch ($propertyname) {
            case 'submittedby':
                $this->submittedby = ucWordsSpace($this->submittedby);
                break;
            case 'phonenumber':
                if (strlen($this->phonenumber) > 0)
                    $this->phonenumber = formatphone($this->phonenumber, false);
                break;
            case 'property':
                $this->unit_options = array();
                $this->unit_values = array();
                $this->unit_values[0] = -1;
                $units = Unit::where('property_id',4)->select('id','abbrev')->orderBy('abbrev')->get();
                $this->unit_options[0] = (count($units) == 0) ? 'Choose Your Property First' : 'Choose Your Unit';
                foreach ($units as $unit) {
                    $this->unit_values[] = $unit->id;
                    $this->unit_options[] = $unit->abbrev;
                }
                dd($this->unit_values, $this->unit_options);
                break;
        }
    }
```

I have the following in layout.app.blade.php in the :

```
 @vite('resources/css/app.css', 'resources/js/app.js')
```

the following is in my tailwind.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  content: [
      "./resources/**/*.blade.php",
      "./resources/**/*.js",
      "./resources/**/*.vue",
  ],
```

resources/css/app.css contains:

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

resources/js/app.js contains:

```
import './bootstrap';
import '../css/app.css';
```

bootstrap.js contains:

```
window._ = _;

/**
 * We'll load the axios HTTP library which allows us to easily issue requests
 * to our Laravel back-end. This library automatically handles sending the
 * CSRF token as a header based on the value of the "XSRF" token cookie.
 */

import axios from 'axios';
window.axios = axios;

window.axios.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'] = 'XMLHttpRequest';

import Alpine from 'alpinejs'
import focus from '@alpinejs/focus'
window.Alpine = Alpine
Alpine.plugin(focus)
Alpine.start()
```

vite.config.js contains:

```
import {defineConfig} from 'vite';
import laravel from 'laravel-vite-plugin';

import livewire from '@defstudio/vite-livewire-plugin'; // <-- import

export default defineConfig({
    //...

    plugins: [
        laravel([
            'resources/css/app.css',
            'resources/js/app.js',
        ]),

        livewire({  // <-- add livewire plugin
            refresh: ['resources/css/app.css'],  // <-- will refresh css (tailwind ) as well
        }),
    ],
});
```

Signed Dazed and Confused!

Hope someone has some insite.

---

okay, i have something to add.  here is a component that I am using

```
@props([
   'label' => '',
   'model' => '',
   'pholder' => '',
   'speed' => '',
])

<div>
    <div class="rounded-md border border-gray-300 px-3 py-2 mb-3 shadow-sm focus-within:border-indigo-600 focus-within:ring-1 focus-within:ring-indigo-600">
        <label for="{{$model}}" class="block text-xs font-medium text-gray-900">{{$label}}</label>
        <input type="text"
               wire:model{{$speed}}="{{$model}}"
               id="{{$model}}"
               class="block w-full border-0 p-0 text-gray-900 placeholder-gray-400 focus:ring-0 sm:text-sm"
               placeholder="{{$pholder}}">
    </div>
    @error($model)<span class="text-red-800 text-xs underline">{{ $message }}</span> @enderror
</div>
```

the livewire component 'calls' this component thus:

```
<x-hab-input label="Phone Number"
       model="phonenumber"
       pholder="(999) 999-9999"
       speed=".lazy" />
```

I have this rule defined in the livewire component:

```
'phonenumber' => ['regex:/^([0-9\s\-\+\(\)]*)$/', 'min:10', 'max:14', 'required'],
```

i have the following code running after the field is updated

```
public function updated($propertyname)
    {

        $this->validateOnly($propertyname, $this->rules(), $this->customMessages());
        switch ($propertyname) {
            case 'submittedby':
                $this->submittedby = ucWordsSpace($this->submittedby);
                break;
            case 'phonenumber':
                if (strlen($this->phonenumber) > 0)
                    $this->phonenumber = formatphone($this->phonenumber, false);
                break;
```

the formatphone() function is a helper function that resides in App/helpers.php.  the function turns a phone number typed like "4045551212" into "(404) 555-1212".  This function works.  It updates the formatting of the phone number.

However, if user types, e.g., less than 10 numbers it will fail the validation, which is supposed to flash the error to the screen.  But, this is another situation where the screen goes blank. gone.  only the background is there.  The {{$slot}} in app.blade.php is left empty.

Answer (score 1):

well, I am both angry at myself and embarassed.  Here is the culprit.  There was a comment at the top of the livewire component.  Damn.  I took it out, and no problems!

```
<!--
  This example requires some changes to your config:

  // tailwind.config.js
  module.exports = {
    // ...
    plugins: [
      // ...
      require('@tailwindcss/forms'),
    ],
  }
-->
<div>
    <div class="w-3/4 mt-5 mx-auto rounded-2xl p-5 bg-slate-100">
    <p class="text-3xl font-serif text-red-900 text-center">Habersham Properties - Maintenance Request</p>
    <div class="hidden sm:block" aria-hidden="true">
```